# Error: Cannot find module '../generated/ts/realm.node'

Tags: node.js, react-native, realm

I am trying to create a node script to seed a realm database as per https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/realm-files/bundle/

I am trying to create the bundle file for a react-native app.

When I try to run my script to create the `.realm` bundle file using,

```bash
$ node seed.js
```

i received the following error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^
Error: Cannot find module '../generated/ts/realm.node'
```

The only thing I have done that was not mentioned in the instructions in the provided above link was to add the `type: module` to my `package.json`

my package.json is very simple:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "realm": "^12.3.0"
  }
}
```

I added `"type": "module"` because before that I was getting the error,

```
 "cannot import from outside of a module" error
```

I am using VSCode on Windows 10.